# Cant get a wpf textbox to bind to my player object

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, datacontext

I have been trying to bind my Player object with my UI.
If the tutorials are correct I do not see why it shouldn't work.
I have my Main window that create an UserControl inside a tabPage when a button is pressed. This user control contains my player. In the main window I will pass a player to the user control.
Here is my main window:

```
 public partial class MainWindow : INotifyPropertyChanged
    { 
        public MainWindow()
        {
            DataContext = this;
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void AddPlayerClick(Object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            AddTabItem("New Player", new AddPlayer(new Player(1, "asd", "asd", new DateTime(1,2,3), "asd", "asd", "asd", "asd", true)));
        }
        public void AddTabItem(String name, UserControl userControl)
        {
            TabItem tab = new TabItem
            {
                Header = name
            };
            userControl.DataContext = userControl;
            tab.Content = userControl;
            TabControl.Items.Add(tab);
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        [NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator]
        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] String propertyName = null)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
```

```
<Window x:Class="Tournament_App.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Tournament_App"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="1920" Width="1080">
    <StackPanel>
        <Menu>
            <MenuItem Header="Players">
                <MenuItem Header="Add Player" Click="AddPlayerClick"/>
            </MenuItem>
        </Menu>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

When the button is clicked a new tab is created and a player gets passed through.
Then in the AddPlayer User Control it set to a private property with a public get/setter.

```
    public partial class AddPlayer : UserControl, INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private Player _player;
        public Player Player
        {
            get { return _player; }
            set { 
                     _player = value; 
                     OnPropertyChanged();
                 }
        }

        public AddPlayer(Player player)
        {
            DataContext = Player;
            InitializeComponent();

            Player = player;
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        [NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator]
        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] String propertyName = null)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
```

I then bind the players first name to a textbox.

```
<UserControl x:Class="Tournament_App.Views.AddPlayer"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Tournament_App.Views"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800" >
   <StackPanel>
        <Label Content="First Name" />
        <TextBox Text="{Binding FirstName, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
   </StackPanel>
```

As far as i can tell the data context is right. And the binding names are all correct, so I dont get why it is not working. Any help would be apreciated. I belive I have too many INotifyProperty changed, but I cant quite figuire out where I need them. As you might be able to tell I am pretty new to Wpf.

Comment: Do you really want to have all your logic in the Window class and the UserControl? Usually with wpf you would like to stick to the mvvm-pattern, where you have a seperate ViewModel class, which is used as DataContext in the View (=MainWindow in your case) for data binding.

Comment: Oh and in your AddPlayer constructor, try initializing your Player property first: ```Player = player```, before you set it as DataContext of your AddPlayer. The way you have it right now, you assign ```null``` as DataContext.

Comment: `DataContext = player`

Comment: In WPF there is a general rule - if it seems hard, there is good chance you are doing it wrong. Not always, but 99% of this applies, and your situation is one of the examples. First of all, set data context in XAML, so that editor can help you with type inference (it works great). Secondly, use MVVM pattern, at first it seems like to much bloat, but it works (especially with some framework). Based on those 2 advices you would add tab item correctly (your version works but it's not how you are supposed to do it) and if DataContex was binded in XAML, you would not have this problem.

Answer (score 0):

First you are setting the `AddPlayer.DataContext` to the uninitialized property `Player` inside the constructor of `AddPlayer`:

```
public AddPlayer(Player player)
{
  DataContext = Player; // Wrong! Property is not initialized.
  InitializeComponent(); // Wrong! InitializeComponent() should be the very first call

  Player = player;
}
```

This might be a typo. Furthermore `InitializeComponent()` should always be the very first call.

But after instantiating `AddPlayer` you override the `DataContext by setting it to the`AddPlayer` itself:

```
public void AddTabItem(String name, UserControl userControl)
{
  TabItem tab = new TabItem
  {
    Header = name
  };
  userControl.DataContext = userControl; // Wrong! This overrides the constructor assignment. 
  tab.Content = userControl;
  TabControl.Items.Add(tab);
}
```

Instead ad the items to the `TabControl.ItemsSource` and let the control handle the `DataContext`. Also never implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` on controls (or `DependencyObject`. Always implement `DependencyProperty` as this has much better perfomance. It's also very likely that the control's properties are the `Binding.Target` and bound to a data source. `Binding.Target` *must*  be a `DependencyProperty`:

**TabItemData.cs**

```
public class TabItemData
{ 
  public TabItemData(string title, Player player)
  {
    this.Title = title;
    this.Player = player;
  }

  public Player Player { get; set; }
  public string Title { get; set; }
}
```

**AddPlayer.xaml.cs**

```
public partial class AddPlayer : UserControl, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
  public AddPlayer()
  {
    InitializeComponent();

    // Player is already the DataContext, set from XAML DataTemplate.
    // Access player like "var player = this.DataContext as Player;"
    // This instance is automatically created by a DataTemplate
  }
}
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{ 
  public static readonly DependencyProperty PlayersProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
  "Players",
  typeof(ObservableCollection<TabItemData>),
  typeof(MainWindow),
  new PropertyMetadata(default(ObservableCollection<TabItemData>)));

  public ObservableCollection<TabItemData> Players
  {
    get => (ObservableCollection<TabItemData>) GetValue(MainWindow.PlayersProperty);
    set => SetValue(MainWindow.PlayersProperty, value);
  }

  public MainWindow()
  {
    InitializeComponent();

    this.DataContext = this;
    this.Players = new ObservableCollection<TabItemData>();
  }

  private void AddPlayerClick(Object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
  {
    this.Players.Add(new TabItemData("New Player", new Player(1, "asd", "asd", new DateTime(1,2,3), "asd", "asd", "asd", "asd", true)));
  }
}
```

**MainWiindow.xaml**

```
<Window x:Name="Window">
  <StackPanel>
    <Menu>
      <MenuItem Header="Players">
        <MenuItem Header="Add Player" Click="AddPlayerClick" />
      </MenuItem>
    </Menu>

    <TabControl ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=Window, Path=Players>
      <TabControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type TabItemData}">
          <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" />
        </DataTemplate>
      </TabControl.ItemTemplate>
      <TabControl.ContentTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type TabItemData}">
          <AddPlayer DataContext="{Binding Player}" />
        </DataTemplate>
      </TabControl.ContentTemplate>
    </TabControl>
  </StackPanel>
</Window>
```